# How can we display an image when the player collide with an object?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, inventory

I'm working on 2D Unity game and I would like to know how we can display an image on my inventory when the player collide with an object. For exemple, if the player collide with a drumstick, the drumstick image appear on the inventory menu.

Best Regards.

Yacine TAZDAIT.

Comment: Please take the tour and read the guidelines. As it is now, your question is too broad. Also try researching and consulting tutorials beforehand

Answer (score 0):

## Method #1

There are many different ways to display an image. For example, you can have an image with an image component, and you switch the component on and off whenever you want the image to appear/disappear. You can do this using code similar to this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI; // Required when Using UI elements.

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image drumstick;

    public void Start()
    {
        toggleDrumstick(); // This will toggle the drumstick. For example, if the drumstick is not being shown at the time, the drumstick will show on the screen. The opposite is true.
    }

    public void toggleDrumstick() {
        drumstick.enabled = !drumstick.enabled;
    }
}
```

## Method #2

The code above is a great solution, but there is a more modular way to do it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI; // Required when Using UI elements.

public class Drumstick : MonoBehaviour
{  
    public static bool enabled = this.image.enabled;
}
```

I recommend the method above. The reason for this is because every script can now access the drumstick's status. For example, your player script can do this.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{  
    void doSomething () {
        Drumstick.enabled = true; // make the image appear.
    }
}
```

For any of these methods to work, make sure your drumstick uses the image component.

**EDIT**:
To answer your question further, here is a way to implement method #2 in your code. In your player script, you can use `OnCollisionEnter` and the method above to make the drumstick appear.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{  
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "drumstick") Drumstick.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

For this to work, make sure that the drumstick has the tag `"drumstick"`.